# How to center a text inside a svg component?

Tags: html, css, svg

I tried to center text element inside svg but it doesn't work at all , and every time I use `transform: translate(...)` it works but when I change `font-size` or the text gets changed its not in the center again. How to solve this? Here is an example:

```
 <button className='giga-button'>
    <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 318 112">
      <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="315" height="109" fill="none" stroke="aqua" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
      <text fill='white' fontSize={"20px"}>
        a button
      </text>
      </svg>
    </button>
```

I tried to use `text-anchor: middle`, but it doesn't work. I expect the text inside the `svg` to be in the **center all of the time**. I also tried some solutions from stackoverflow, but they didn't work for me. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You are missing some props.

Setting `x="50%"` and `y="50%"` will put your text in a middle, but it doesn't know the height and width or your text. In other words the left bottom center of the box, that contains your text will be in the middle. To change this you need to add those 2 props along with those coordinates:

- `dominant-baseline="middle"` [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty)

> **middle**
>
> The rendered characters are shifted such that the geometric middle of the resulting rendered text (determined from the initial and final current text position before applying the text-anchor property) is at the initial current text position.

- `text-anchor="middle"` [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty)

> **middle**
>
> The baseline-identifier for the dominant-baseline is set to be 'middle'. The derived baseline-table is constructed from the defined baselines in a baseline-table in the nominal font. That font baseline -table is chosen using the following priority order of baseline-table names: 'alphabetic', 'ideographic', 'hanging', 'mathematical'. The baseline-table font-size is changed to the value of the ‘font-size’ property on this element.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 318 112">
  <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="315" height="109" fill="none" stroke="aqua" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" font-size="20px">
    a button
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: oh i didn't know about x and y , i was just trying text-anchor and it wasn't working, its working now , thank you :)